# Set $X$ has $n$ elements, and set $Y$ has $m$ elements. Prove by induction that $X$ into $Y$ has $n^m$ elements.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found this problem in a discrete mathematics textbook but there is no solutions provided for me to see how it was done.

I started by making the inductive hypothesis, assume $n^m$ is true. 
The base case should be $m = 1$.

But from there I'm not sure where to go.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Do they have anything to do with $X$ and $Y$? And what does "$A$ into $B$" mean?

Comment: @bof I can't read straight I'd mixed up two questions. I have made the correct edit now.

Comment: That's better, but what does "$X$ into $Y$" mean??